# Alpha channel with DXT5 compressed texture

Tags: c++, opengl, image-compression

I've written a test program using OpenGL on OS X that loads a PNG, compresses it in memory to DXT5 using libsquish (http://code.google.com/p/libsquish/), and textures a plane.

When I upload an image that contains an alpha channel, but no pixels have alpha values other than fully opaque, it displays correctly: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WlRcD.png

Given the same image but the black part is replaced with transparency, this is the output I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOPqA.png

The code is not pretty, it is a thrown together proof of concept:

1. The C++ source: http://pastebin.com/m0RqpgUS
2. The vertex shader: http://pastebin.com/QyaWCaTk
3. The fragment shader: http://pastebin.com/KEuFJ83C
4. The test images: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/4597377/images.zip

Any thoughts?

Comment: What happens if you use an off-line tool to generate your compressed data, rather than some library you found on Google Code?

Comment: Are you sure that your alpha value is always 255 ? I use squish on a daily basis and it does preserve alpha allright. Can you post the 'reference' code that you used to create your correct image ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I forgot this:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```